# Assigning a DateTime value to the variable by fetching a table from a csv file

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0

```
DateTime someDate = DateTime.Parse(row[table.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString());
```

Suppose if the file has no date in specific column and I want to pass a null value, how can I achieve this?

I want to achieve this in one line ... also note that I am using C# ASP.NET MVC ... Thanks.

Comment: By the way i can pass null value to the variable like this. 

`DateTime? someDate= row[table.Columns[1].ColumnName] as DateTime?;`
But i want pass date value if file columns[1] has a value, other wise null. Also I have tried using Coalescing and tertiary operators

Comment: If the data is already a `DateTime?` you don't need to convert it to a string and parse it back into a date, just cast the object directly.

Comment: @ChrisF i have this line of code.
`DateTime someDate = DateTime.Parse(row[table.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString());`
but it fails if the column read from file is Empty

Comment: Yes, I know. You keep saying that. However, if the data is already a `DateTime` **you don't need to convert it to a string and parse it**, just cast it: `someDate = (DateTime?)row[table.Columns[1].ColumnName];`

Comment: it still throwing an error. i checked it both by having value and with empty value
`DateTime? someDate= (DateTime?)row[table.Columns[1].ColumnName];`
But i can passed the error by doing below line of code if i have a date value in csv file. but if its null getting error
`DateTime someDate = DateTime.Parse(row[table.Columns[1].ColumnName].ToString());`
if someone can help please suggest me a doing it better way. Thanks

Comment: It will give an error if it's null. Trying to call `ToString` on a null variable **will** give a `NullReferenceException`. You need to check it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable DateTime could be helpful:

```
DateTime ? dateTime;
```

Then you can use it like a normal DateTime object or nullify it:

```
dateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
dateTime = null;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have solved it by creating another function to check datenull by passing datetime as argument and checking datetime != string.Empty returns true, otherwise null.